# Redis client servicestack Timeout

Tags: redis, servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack RedisClient for caching. How can I set a timeout? For example if the result is longer than 5 secs to return null?
Anyone knows?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some operations like blocking LPOP/RPOP that includes a timeout.

In general redis runs in memory and is extremely fast so its rare that it timesout on its own. However the Network can be down so RedisNativeClient (the base class for RedisClient) includes a `SendTimeout` which you can set to do this.

Comment: Additionally, setting the SocketSendTimeout on a PooledRedisClientManager will  ensure that every client is initialised with the appropriate SendTimeout.